# Controller(s) for a page that can save multiple AR models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a handful of pages that are almost dashboard-like. On a single page, I might have 2 or more individual forms that need to post to an action to save different AR models in the DB. As of right now, I'm just using a single controller with specific routes defined for creating each record (create_task, create_followup, etc). Since the page itself doesn't follow a typical MVC pattern, I'm not expecting to be able to have clean controllers with the typical show/new/create/etc. I can't change the feeling, though, that a lot of this can be abstracted out.

I tried creating a controller for each model and posting to that from the respective forms, but that caused issues when a model failed validation and needed to be returned to the original route that I had posted from.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Continue with your "controller for each model" path. When a model validation fails, just render your main page.

```
class ExamplesController > ApplicationController
  def create
    example = Example.new(params[:example])
    if example.save
      # do the happy thing
    else
      render "home#index"
    end
  end
end
```

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller, it has some more about it.

Comment: This kills my ability to return the user to the form that failed the validation and present the errors, though (forms are build using form_for), doesn't it?

Comment: In your individual controllers just have it render the page they came from on failure, and set the errors in the flash.